# Leonard Susskind said that the small value of the cosmological constant could mean that the universe is much bigger than we thought. Why?

Tags: universe, cosmological-constant, observable-universe, fine-tuning

He said that near the beginning of [this Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cT4zZIHR3s) that it could mean that the universe is much bigger than he had thought that it was, and that the cosmological constant wasn't even a constant. I don't have a clue what his reasoning was though.

Comment: Where did he say this? In a book? In a scientific paper? What did he actually say? We don't even know if the universe is closed or open, so it doesn't make sense to talk about how big it is. If it's open, it's infinitely big.

Comment: He said it near the beggining of this video

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cT4zZIHR3s

Comment: I watched the first half of the video, up to the point where Susskind got on to the anthropic explanation, and at no point does Susskind say what you claim. Can you give a precise time into the video that he says it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't watch enough of the video to see the alleged claim, but I'm almost sure he is talking about the idea that the universe has different regions in which the "constants" of nature have different values, and only a few of those regions are hospitable to intelligent life, and we (of necessity) live in one of those, and that's why the constants here seem to have fine-tuned values. The universe would be much bigger than we thought because it would include not only our whole cosmos of galaxies, but also a bunch of other regions. The word "multiverse" is often used for this, but it makes as much sense, if not more, to just call it the universe since the word "universe" normally includes everything that exists.

Many physicists consider the tiny size of the cosmological constant (in natural units) to be evidence for this idea, because it's pretty clear that no intelligent life could evolve if it were close to its apparently natural value (no large structures could exist at all), and no one can figure out a theoretical way to make it small except for extremely complicated (and hence apparently unlikely) constructions in string theory.